# failed to import module in another jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I have 2 jupyter notebooks, first one is named friedman_1.ipynb and I defined a class. In 2nd jupyter notebook, I can import it without error. However I got an error when calling the class method. see below. Thanks for your help.

```
class Friedman1Test:
    """This class encapsulates the Friedman1 regression test for feature selection
    """

    VALIDATION_SIZE = 0.20
    NOISE = 1.0

    def __init__(self, numFeatures, numSamples, randomSeed):
        """
        :param numFeatures: total number of features to be used (at least 5)
        :param numSamples: number of samples in dataset
        :param randomSeed: random seed value used for reproducible results
        """

        self.numFeatures = numFeatures
        self.numSamples = numSamples
        self.randomSeed = randomSeed
```

in 2nd jupyter notebook, I am trying to import the module and call its class method, then I got an error

```
from ipynb.fs.full.friedman_1 import *

# create the Friedman-1 test class:
friedman = friedman_1.Friedman1Test(NUM_OF_FEATURES, NUM_OF_SAMPLES, RANDOM_SEED)
friedman

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-48edeee5c421> in <module>
      1 # create the Friedman-1 test class:
----> 2 friedman = friedman_1.Friedman1Test(NUM_OF_FEATURES, NUM_OF_SAMPLES, RANDOM_SEED)
      3 friedman

NameError: name 'friedman_1' is not defined
```

Comment: call `Friedman1Test()` directly instead of the `friedman_1.Friedman1Test()`, as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from ipynb.fs.full.friedman_1 import *

# create the Friedman-1 test class:
friedman = Friedman1Test(NUM_OF_FEATURES, NUM_OF_SAMPLES, RANDOM_SEED)
friedman
```

You have already imported the class when you use the asterisk, you just need to call the class constructor directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are already importing all the functions and classes into the notebook. Try the following directly. -

```
from ipynb.fs.full.friedman_1 import *

friedman = Friedman1Test(NUM_OF_FEATURES, NUM_OF_SAMPLES, RANDOM_SEED)
friedman
```